# Google Sheets Conditional formatting for items changing accross sheets in same workbook

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-docs

I am tracking track atheletes times accross different track meets. I have each tract meet on a different tab with the times for each event. Then I have a main tab that lists all of their PRs (personal bests) for the season.

I want to highlight cells in each tab after a track meet if they run their personal best time. How can I do this? I want Google Sheets to look at the PR sheet and if it matches the corresponding cell in a current track meet tab, highlight that cell.

For example,
Athlete A ran a track meet today. On this sheet, I have entered a time of 00:14.7 in cell B3 on sheet 'Meet 1'. I want this cell to be highlighted IF this number is less than the number on 'PRs'  sheet cell B3

I have tried conditional formatting with no luck referencing another sheet

Comment: Share a sample workbook then explain what you are trying to do. Do some google research on conditional formatting.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output